# ввод даты с клавиатуры

Tags: java, дата

подскажите, пожалуйста. Как сделать ввод даты с клавиатуры, если значение месяца может вводиться в виде числа (1–12) или в виде сокращенной строки («Янв.»–«Дек.»).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну если всего два варианта можно костыльно вот так попробовать. Работает для строк вида "1.12.1992" и "1.Dec.1992". С Локальностью только поковыряться осталось.

```
private Date date;
    try {
        date  = new SimpleDateFormat("d.MMM.yyyy").parse("YOUR_STRING");
      
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        date  = new SimpleDateFormat("d.M.yyyy").parse("YOUR_STRING");
    }
```